# ionic serve throws TypeError: express is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework

i have an simple ionic1 project, and when i run `ionic serve` command in windows command prompt i get this logs and errors:

```
[INFO] Starting server: --port=8100 --p=8100 --livereload-port=35729 --r=35729 --address=0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel

TypeError: express is not a function
```

and i don't know where should i check to solve this error.

this is **ionic.config.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "n_mobile",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic1",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/n1",
      "proxyUrl": "http://178.162.206.144:81/n1"
    },
    {
      "path": "/c1",
      "proxyUrl": "http://178.162.206.144:81/c1"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://178.162.206.144:81/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will work for Ionic 1, but you can try this:

run npm the command within your project directory.

```
npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```